# How to create a tool window in VS2019 extension

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am wanting to create a VS extension which will show a dockable tool window similar to say toolbox or Task List.

I have created a VS Extension (VSIX) project.
When I run it my menu entry appears under "Extensions" and when I click on that the method class is run, specifically executing the "Execute" method where I have a simple ShowMessageBox just to indicate that the menu option is working.

I get that message so the framework is all working.
But I need the tool window to appear and from what I **have** discovered, once that window is created I essentially have a blank "canvas" to add normal controls like butttons textboxes, grids etc.

I have researched lots of articles, etc. but haven't been able to find a clear statement of what comes next for the window to be created and made visible.

Can anyone please point me to clear, detailed steps to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Samples/tree/master/ToolWindow

Comment: I think the link that Hans shared is very useful, have you referred to that sample and made some progress?